# Spock and Groovy: variable assignment results in null

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, junit, spock

I have a problem with a test in Spock:

```
@Subject
def mutation = new OrderedServicesMutation(long list of constructor elements here)

def "should order service and create address"() {
    given:
    def command = new OrderServiceCommand(1L, 2L, new Date(), "SomeAddress")
    def user = new User(id: command.userId)
    def address = new String()
    def service = new Service(id: command.serviceId)
    and:
    userRepository.findById(command.userId) >> Optional.of(user)
    serviceRepository.findById(command.serviceId) >> Optional.of(service)

    when:
    def result = mutation.orderService(command)

    then:
    with(result) {
        user == user
        address == address
        service == service
    }
}
```

**OrderedServicesMutation.java:**

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OrderedServicesMutation implements GraphQLMutationResolver {

// imports removed for readibility

    @Transactional
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER','USER')")
public OrderedService orderService(OrderServiceCommand command) {
    OrderedService orderedService = orderedServiceRepository.save(
            orderedServiceMapper.mapWithHistory(
                    userRepository.findById(command.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(User.class)),
                    command.getAddress(),
                    serviceRepository.findById(command.getServiceId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(Service.class)),
                    command.getDate()
            )
    );
    orderedServicePublisher.publish(orderedService);

    return orderedService;
}
```

The method should return an object of type `OrderedService`, and it normally is during runtime, but when I am running this test, I get:

```
Target of 'with' block must not be null
```

Debugging the test shows me that the `result` variable is null...

Why is Spock not assigning the result of `mutation.orderService(command)` to the `result` variable?

Comment: I think you should post a `orderService` method implementation. WIthout the code it's hard to say actually anything.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Using something like `user==user` looks extremly odd and i'd expect that to always be true

Comment: @dziki What are `orderedServiceMapper` object and `mapWithHistory` method? I cannot see them in your test. I'm also assuming `orderedServiceRepository` from the implementation is `serviceRepository` from your test, right?

Comment: Ok, just found that `serviceRepository` is not a `orderedServiceRepository`. In general, your method will return the same object what `orderedServiceRepository.save`. Seems it isn't mocked so it returns `null`. Am I right?

Comment: it is mocked, but it still returns `null`...

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a complete example without any missing dependencies. Otherwise it is just speculation why your test fails. Even the test itself is incomplete, e.g. nobody knows where `userRepository` and `serviceRepository` come from or how they are being used. What I can tell you, though, is that most probably not Spock is the problem as you think. I am assuming that the result is assigned correctly, just the result is `null` due to the way you set up and execute your test.

Comment: Agree with @kriegaex. Actually, on the surface it is simple: there's something in the call chain in the given service under test with the parameters you pass - that just returns null. Though it's impossible to nail it without being able to see through it. And, uh, yes - that "then" part with "with" is just ridiculous. Better don't do things like that, ever - you're tricking yourself.

Comment: Is OrderServiceMapper a component? Should it be mocked for preserving the unit test isolation? If this class has any dependencies of its own, it could present a problem for your unit test. Like others stated before, we need more context on the inner workings of your logic there, but I tried to provide an answer for you below.

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the answer of Repository.save to have it return whatever it received during test execution:

```
and:
1 * orderedServiceRepository.save(_) >> { args -> args[0] }
```

Not that declaring receiving anything `(_)` would be a good practice in most cases. At least, you could specify the type of the argument like so: `(_ as OrderedService)`.

Also using a closure would be Groovier:

```
result.with {
  assert it.user == user
  assert it.address == address
  assert it.service == service
}
```

I think you need the asserts inside the closure, not sure about when using it as a function like you did.

It's also a good practice to add the cardinality so you know how many times a mock was called.

By the end, you could also make sure no more interactions were made to any of the declared mocks, which is great for making sure there aren't any unexpected interactions:

```
and: 'No more interactions'
0 * _
```

This is how I'd write this Specification:

```
def "should order service and create address"() {
    given:
    def command = new OrderServiceCommand(1L, 2L, new Date(), "SomeAddress")
    def user = new User(id: command.userId)
    def address = new String()
    def service = new Service(id: command.serviceId)

    when:
    def result = mutation.orderService(command)

    then:
    1 * userRepository.findById(command.userId) >> Optional.of(user)

    and: 
    1 * serviceRepository.findById(command.serviceId) >> Optional.of(service)

    and:
    1 * orderedServiceRepository.save(_ as OrderedService) >> { args -> args[0] }

    and: 'Make sure Publisher receives correct OrderedService' // if you wish to do so
    1 * orderedServicePublisher.publish(_) >> { OrderedService arg ->
      assert arg.user == user
      assert arg.address == address
      assert arg.service == service
    }

    and: // don't really see why use with closure here
    result.user == user
    result.address == address
    result.service == service

    and: 'No more interactions'
    0 * _
}
```

Comment: There are other improvements I'd make, but they might be outside the scope here. I hope that helps.